# Is there a way to get Windows login password hint from SAM hive with volatility?

Tags: windows, forensics, memory, registry, volatility

We know that every user in Windows has a password hint. This password hint is stored in the SAM hive, more specifically in the `SAM\Domains\Account\Users` path. Is there a way to extract this password hint of a user with volatility if we have a memory dump of that computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "UserPasswordHint" key on Windows 8 (and Windows 7) is stored in the following location:

HKLM\SAM\SAM\Domains\Account\Users<userkey>\UserPasswordHint

But the HINT was encrypted. There is a way to dump values from registry strings. Using hivedump then pass the offset of the hive and the path using volatility

To Decrypt the values here is the sample code:

```
def decode_windows_hint(e_string)
    d_string = ""
    e_string.scan(/..../).each do |chunk|
        bytes = chunk.scan(/../)
        d_string += (bytes[1] + bytes[0]).to_s.hex.chr
    end
    d_string
end
```

[Adding Windows User Password Hint Decoding to Hashdump Tools #706](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/pull/706/commits/fbc36b57d0aa83449c9fe5bec235864f4ec62960)

Comment: Can this also be applied to windows 10?